# joinbylocationsummary with loop on the same input layer using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, shapefile, qgis-processing, spatial-join, loop

I have adapted a script to use `"qgis:joinbylocationsummary"` in a loop.

I would like to adapt it so the loop adds all the *.shp* of the directory 'layers_I_want_to_add' to join their maximum to filosofi17_fc.shp, in the same *.shp* at the end. So each maximum of the 'layers_I_want_to_add' is a new column in my filosofi17_fc.shp.

````py
# importe la boite a outils traitements, pour pouvoir utiliser ses algorithmes
import processing
# import des autres modules Python necessaires
import os

#################################
# parametres
# A ADAPTER
#################################

# parametres en entree
input_folder = 'K:/exemple/layers_I_want_to_add/'
join_layer = 'K:/exemple/filosofi17_fc.shp'

# parametres en sortie (le repertoire doit deja exister)
output_folder = 'K:/out/'

#############################################################################

# recupere la liste de tous les shapefiles presents dans input_folder
list_shp = [file for file in os.listdir(input_folder) if file.endswith('.shp')]
print ('list_shp : ' + str(list_shp))

# pour chacun des elements de list_shp
for shp in list_shp:
    # recupere le chemin et le nom de chaque couche en entree
    input_layer = input_folder + shp
    print (input_layer)
    # recupere l emplacement et le nom des couches qui seront creees
    output_name = output_folder + shp[:-4] + '_maxconc.shp'
    print (output_name)
    # lance l'algorithme joinbylocationsummary pour chacune des couches
    # (cf. onglet help de cet algorithme pour savoir comment l'appeler)
    processing.run('qgis:joinbylocationsummary', {"INPUT": join_layer, "JOIN": input_layer,"PREDICATE":[0,1],"JOIN_FIELDS":'CONCAN',"SUMMARIES":'3', "OUTPUT": output_name})
print ('jointure ok')```
````